# How to move rviz 3D view with keyboard ("W,A,S,D", etc.)?

Tags: rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible in rviz to use keyboard key presses to enable movement of 3D camera view, instead of using mouse clicks and drags?
For example, I hope to press key "W" to move forward, "A" to left, "D" to right, "Z" for up, etc.

Or if this is currently not possible in rviz, how can I develop a plugin to enable that (which class to inherit and functions to override)?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200640/how-to-move-rviz-3d-view-with-keyboard-(%22w,a,s,d%22,-etc.)?/) by [Wanli](https://answers.ros.org/users/21326/wanli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's the [fps_motion_tool](https://github.com/hdeeken/fps_motion_tool), an rviz plugin that does exactly what you want. Not sure about its current status, but if you run into problems, I'm sure the author (hdeeken) will be happy to help you.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wanli](https://answers.ros.org/users/21326/wanli/) on 2015-01-12**:
thanks! This solved my problem!
the package was still on rosbuild thus cannot be used in indigo, but after minor fix it works well.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-01-12**:
Good to hear! If you want, you can open a pull request with your changes.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-12**:
@Wanli, I just wanted to let others know, rosbuild packages can be used in indigo, you just have to download and build them yourself, i.e. you can't have the ROS farm build binaries for rosbuild packages on indigo, see: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014

**Comment by [Wanli](https://answers.ros.org/users/21326/wanli/) on 2015-01-12**:
Just got an update from the author hdeeken, the original repository (fps_motion_tool) is obsolete. Please use [rviz_fps_plugin](https://github.com/uos/rviz_fps_plugin) now.
Also pull request (catkin upgrade) was created and merged to the new repository.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to the answer of @130s, you might be interested in the [rviz_animated_view_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_animated_view_controller). Not a keyboard interface, but it does allow you to control the RViz camera by other means than the mouse.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1